# Implications of inequalities

Tags: probability, inequality

For $i=1,2,3$, consider a random variable $Y_i$ taking value in 
$$
\mathcal{Y}:=\{(1,1), (1,0), (0,1), (0,0)\}
$$ and a random closed set $S_i$ taking value in $\mathcal{S}$ that is the power set of $\mathcal{Y}$ (without the empty set), i.e.
$$
\mathcal{S}:=\{\{(1,1)\}, \{(1,0)\}, \{(0,1)\}, \{(0,0)\},\\ \{(1,1), (1,0)\}, \{(1,1), (0,1)\}, \{(1,1), (0,0)\}, \{(1,0), (0,1)\}, \{(1,0), (0,0)\}, \{(0,1), (0,0)\},\\ \{(1,1), (1,0), (0,1)\}, \{(1,1), (1,0), (0,0)\}, \{(1,1), (0,1), (0,0)\}, \{(1,0), (0,1), (0,0)\},\\ \{(1,1), (1,0), (0,1), (0,0)\}\}
$$
$Y_i,S_i$ are defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.

Also, $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ are independent, $S_1, S_2, S_3$ are independent.

---

Suppose that
$$
P(Y_i\in K)\leq P(S_i\cap K\neq \emptyset) \text{ } \forall K \in \mathcal{S} \text{ for } i=1,2,3
$$

For example, for $K=\{(1,1), (0,1)\}$ and $i=1$
$$
P(Y_1=(1,1))+P(Y_1=(0,1))\leq \\
P(S_1=\{(1,1)\})+P(S_1=\{(0,1)\})\\+P(S_1=\{(1,1), (1,0)\})+P(S_1= \{(1,1), (0,1)\})\\+P(S_1=\{(1,1), (0,0)\})+P(S_1=\{(1,0), (0,1)\})+P(S_1=\{(0,1), (0,0)\})\\+P(S_1= \{(1,1), (1,0), (0,1)\})+P(S_1=\{(1,1), (1,0), (0,0)\})\\+P(S_1= \{(1,1), (0,1), (0,0)\})+P(S_1= \{(1,0), (0,1), (0,0)\})\\+P(S_1= \{(1,1), (1,0), (0,1), (0,0)\})
$$

---

**I would like your help to show that** 
$$
(\star) \hspace{1cm}
P(Y_1=(1,1))\times P(Y_2=(1,1))\times P(Y_3=(1,1)) +\\P(Y_1=(0,0))\times P(Y_2=(0,0))\times P(Y_3=(0,0))\leq\\
 P(S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ OR }\\
 S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset)
$$

---

**My attempt**

(A) I take the inequalities referred to $K=\{(1,1), (0,0)\}$ for $i=1,2,3$ and multiply them across $i$: 
$$
[P(Y_1=(1,1))+P(Y_1=(0,0))]\times [P(Y_2=(1,1))+P(Y_2=(0,0))]\times [P(Y_3=(1,1))+P(Y_3=(0,0))]\leq\\ [P(S_1\cap \{(1,1),(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset)]\times [P(S_2\cap \{(1,1),(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset)]\times [P(S_3\cap \{(1,1),(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset)]
$$

(B) On the lhs the terms "in excess" with respect to $(\star)$ are
$$
P(Y_1=(1,1))\times P(Y_2=(0,0))\times P(Y_3=(0,0))+\\
P(Y_1=(0,0))\times P(Y_2=(1,1))\times P(Y_3=(0,0))+\\
P(Y_1=(0,0))\times P(Y_2=(0,0))\times P(Y_3=(1,1))+\\
P(Y_1=(1,1))\times P(Y_2=(1,1))\times P(Y_3=(0,0))+\\
P(Y_1=(1,1))\times P(Y_2=(0,0))\times P(Y_3=(1,1))+\\
P(Y_1=(0,0))\times P(Y_2=(1,1))\times P(Y_3=(1,1))
$$

(C) On the rhs the terms "in excess" with respect to $(\star)$ are
$$
P(S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)+\\
P(S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)+\\
P(S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)+\\
P(S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)+\\
P(S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)+\\
P(S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)+\\
P(S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)+\\
P(S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)+\\
P(S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)+\\
P(S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)+\\
P(S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}= \emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq\emptyset)+\\
P(S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}=\emptyset)\times P(S_2\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap \{(0,0)\}= \emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap \{(0,0)\}\neq\emptyset)
$$

(D) One strategy could be to show that (B) $\geq $ (C), and, hence, because of (A), $(\star)$ holds. However, I am unable to do it.

(E) What I have shown, instead, is that
$$
1-P(Y_1=(0,0))=P(Y_1=(1,1))+P(Y_1=(1,0))+P(Y_1=(0,1))\geq\\ P(S_1\cap \{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset)
$$
and
$$
P(Y_1=(1,1))\geq P(S_1=\{(1,1)\})
$$
and
$$
P(Y_1=(1,1))+P(Y_1=(0,0))\geq P(S_1\cap\{(1,1)\}\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_1\cap\{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset\})
$$
and
$$
P(Y_1=(1,1))+P(Y_1=(0,0))\geq P(S_1\cap\{(0,1),(1,0)\}=\emptyset)
$$
which, however, do not seem to be useful.

Comment: I will spare you your hard-earned reputation by restoring the bounty and migrating this to the Math site where it is more likely to be answered.

Comment: Can we assume independence between the various random variables?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that $P(Y_1\in K_1\text{ and } Y_2\in K_2 \text{ and } Y_3\in K_3)=P(Y_1\in K_1) \times P(Y_2\in K_2)\times P(Y_3\in K_3)$ and $P(S_1\cap K_1\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_2\cap K_2\neq \emptyset \text{ and } S_3\cap K_3\neq \emptyset)=P(S_1\cap K_1\neq \emptyset) \times P(S_2\cap K_2\neq \emptyset)\times P(S_3\cap K_3\neq \emptyset)$.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I have added it to the main body.

Comment: Question edited because some terms were missing in C)

Comment: This seems grossly overcomplicated. For example, you state that we assume $P(Y_i\in K)\leq P(S_i\cap K\neq \phi)$. My understanding of this is you only consider the r.h.s. when $S_i\cap K\neq \phi$, i.e. fix $S_i$ and then consider sets $K$ such that $S_i\cap K\neq \phi$. Yet in this case, the inequality is a trivial consequence of the laws of probability.

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks for your help, but I am not sure I follow your hint. Could you write down something to explain better? I am struggling over this problem..

Comment: Am I interpreting this correctly by saying that for $i \neq j, $ then $P(S_i \cap K_i \neq \emptyset \text{ AND } S_j \cap K_j \neq \emptyset) = P(S_i \cap K_i \neq \emptyset) \cdot P(S_j \cap K_j \neq \emptyset), $ and $P(S_i \cap K_i \neq \emptyset \text{ OR } S_j \cap K_j \neq \emptyset) = P(S_i \cap K_i \neq \emptyset) + P(S_j \cap K_j \neq \emptyset)$?

Comment: The first expression is OK. The second is wrong: it could be that $S_i$ and $S_j$ hit $K_i$ and $K_j$; in other words, the events $S_i\cap K_i\neq \emptyset$ and $S_j\cap K_j\neq \emptyset$ are not disjoint.

Comment: In which case $P(S_i  \cap K_i \neq \emptyset\: \text{OR} \: S_j \cap K_j \neq \emptyset) = P(S_i  \cap K_i \neq \emptyset) + P(S_j  \cap K_j \neq \emptyset) - P(S_i  \cap K_i \neq \emptyset\: \text{AND} \: S_j \cap K_j \neq \emptyset)  = P(S_i  \cap K_i \neq \emptyset) + P(S_j  \cap K_j \neq \emptyset) - P(S_i  \cap K_i \neq \emptyset)\cdot P(S_j \cap K_j \neq \emptyset)?$

Comment: That is correct.